# Stop Radio Button Running Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry, kinda new to jQuery been doing some reading but been unable to find a solution.

I have a radio button that on click runs some jQuery:

```
<input type="radio" id="op5" value="1" name="options2" class="custom" />
```

On clicking this radio button the following jQuery runs to do multiple things on the page

```
    jQuery('#op5').click(function () {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').trigger('click');
        $(".white").attr('class', 'white checked');
        $(".blue").attr('class', 'blue checked');
        $(".sub_label").attr('class', 'sub_label')
        $(".sub_label checked").attr('class', 'sub_label')

    });
```

At the moment if the user re-clicks the radio button it re runs and will uncheck the checkboxes as it re runs the line

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').trigger('click');
```

Is there a way I can stop the code in my jQuery function running for a second time?

JS Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jqh3L8t6/

Comment: Make fiddle - ant it will be easier to help

Comment: `jQuery('#op5').one("click" , function () {`

Comment: @JqueryKing pls put it as answer

Comment: Do you want it to only run once, or only when checked (i.e. if another radio is selected do you want to re-enable the function)?

Comment: @redbmk That would be useful.

Comment: @Legend1989, sorry, which one would be useful? Running only once, or running only when checked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `.one()` in jquery it triggers only one time. Use `.addClass()` instead of add `attr()` for class

```
jQuery('#op5').one("click" , function () {
          $('input[type=checkbox]').trigger('click');
          $(".white").addClass('white checked');
          $(".blue").addClass('blue checked');
          $(".sub_label :checked").addClass('sub_label')

 });
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jqh3L8t6/1/)

Comment: The only thing is `addClass` will add those classes but overwriting the `class` attribute will also remove any other classes. Probably OP just wants to add classes but the other method isn't necessarily wrong depending on the desired outcome.